# suppose a>1 is an integer, and p is an odd prime number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function, primitive-roots

Suppose $a>1$ is an integer, and $p$ is an odd prime number. Prove that each odd prime factor of $(a^p)-1$ which does not divide $a-1$ should be in the form $2pt+1$.

My Approaching:
($a^p)-1$ is divisible by q which is any odd prime factor of $(a^p)-1$.
then I rewrite the function $(a^p)-1 as (a-1)*((a^p-1)+...+1)$
So whether $q$ divides $(a-1)$ or "the rest"
Then I stuck because I do not know how make "the rest" equal to $2pt+1$.

Thanks

Comment: $(3)$ of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime#Theorems_about_Mersenne_numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $q$ is prime, $q\ne2$ and $q\mid a^p-1$ but $q\not\mid a-1$.  Writing the last two conditions in congruence form,
$$a^p\equiv1\pmod q\quad\hbox{but}\quad a\not\equiv1\pmod q\ .$$
This means <*please supply reasons*> that the order of $a$ modulo $q$ is $p$, and hence $p$ is a factor of $q-1$.  See if you can complete the proof.

Comment: Thank you. It's very helpful

Comment: The  "supplied reason" is the [Order Test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1188614/242).