# Efficiently prove $2$ generates $(\mathbb{Z}/19\mathbb{Z})^*$ [Order Testing]

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

So I'm first asked to compute, mod 19, the powers of 2,

$$2^{2},2^{3},2^{6},2^{9}$$

which I compute as

$$4,8,7,18$$

respectively.

I'm then asked to prove that 2 generates $(\mathbb{Z}/19\mathbb{Z})^{*}$ based on the above.  I'm not seeing how you can only look at these powers to know that 2 generates the group.  Of course I could compute the rest of the powers of 2 and show that all $1\leq a\leq 18$ are congruent to $2^{k}$ for some integer $k$, but I get the impression that this is not what I'm supposed to be seeing here.

What I am noticing is that I've basically computed $2^{2}$ and $2^{3}$ and then a few combinations of them.  Trivially I can get $1$ as $2^{0}$ and 2 likewise, and I'm allowed to take negative integer powers so I must get $2^{-1}$.  If I somehow knew that $2^{-1}$ were not $4, 8, 7,$ or $18$ then that would be nice, but I don't see how I can be assured of that without explicit calculation--and I get the feeling this is supposed to be an exercise in not explicitly calculating these.

Maybe this is supposed to be "half calculation", like showing that because I can get $4\cdot 8=32$ and $4\cdot 7=28$ I must therefore be able to obtain ... I don't know what.  Any hints?  Or am I over-thinking this and I should just calculate every power of 2?

Comment: $(\Bbb Z/19\Bbb Z)^{\ast}$ has order 18. To conclude $2$ is a generator, we need to eliminate $2,3,6$ and $9$ as possible orders, because, you know, Lagrange.

Comment: @DavidWheeler Actually, technically I *don't* know Lagrange. :) Well, I do, but I'm not supposed to.  For now the class has only proved the special case for finite cyclic groups, that a number divides the order iff it is the order of a subgroup.  Which makes me realize, actually, I can't use the fact that this group's subgroups must have order dividing 18 because I haven't proved its cyclic.  Looks like I have more work to do.

Comment: @David Actually you only need to eliminate *maximal* proper divisors of $18$ - see my answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque Indeed, that was pointed out by Hagen von Eitzen, who posted his answer as I was writing my comment.

Comment: @Aden Even in the absence of Lagrange, it should be clear that if $\langle a\rangle$ has $18$ elements, it generates $(\Bbb Z/19\Bbb Z)^{\ast}$, and if it has lesser order, it does not. One does not need Lagrange to show that $a^k = e \implies o(a)|k$, the division algorithm will suffice.

Comment: @David Wheeler, true, but don't you still need Lagrange (or the like) to establish that the only possible subgroup sizes are those listed, so that they're the only ones you have to check? Once you know that, then you can eliminate all other sizes than 18 and then use what you say.

Comment: @Addem We're not talking about "all" subgroups (since you do not know if $(\Bbb Z/19\Bbb Z)^{\ast}$ is indeed cyclic to start with), we are merely deciding between "generator" and "non-generator" which is an easier task.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If $2$ does not generate the whole order-18 group, it generates a proper subgroup of order dividing $18$, that is, of order $1$ or $2$ or $3$ or $6$ or $9$, which means that one of $2^1, 2^2, 2^3, 2^6, 2^9$ would be $\equiv 1$.

Um, actually ... it suffices to know that $2^9\not\equiv 1$ and $2^6\not\equiv 1$. Do you see why?

Comment: Yep, that makes sense.

Answer (score 8):

By Fermat $\,2^{\large 18} \equiv 1,\,$ thus $\, 2\,$ has order $18\,$ iff $\,2^{\large 6}\!\not\equiv 1$ and $\,2^{\large 9}\!\not\equiv 1\,$ by the following

**Order Test** $\ \,a\,$ has order $\,n\iff \color{#0a0}{a^{\large n} \equiv 1}\,$ but $\,a^{\large n/p} \not\equiv 1\,$ for every prime $\,p\mid n.\,$

**Proof** $\ (\Leftarrow)\ $ By [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242) $\,a\,$ has $\,\color{#c00}{{\rm order}\ k}\,$ dividing $\,\color{#0a0}n.\,$ If $\:k < n\,$ then $\,k\,$ is *proper* divisor of $\,n\,$ therefore $\,k\,$ arises by deleting at least one prime $\,p\,$ from the (unique) prime factorization of $\,n,\,$ hence $\,k\mid n/p,\,$ say $\, kj = n/p,\ $ so $\ a^{\large n/p} \equiv (\color{#c00}{a^{\large k}})^{\large j}\equiv \color{#c00}1^{\large j}\equiv 1,\,$ contra hypothesis. $\ (\Rightarrow)\ $ Clear, since by definition, $\, {\rm ord}(a) = n\,$ is the *least* exponent $\,k>0\,$ such that $\,a^k\equiv 1,\,$ so $\,a^{n/p}\not\equiv 1$.

---

Another handy order test is the converse below, with $\,o(a) := $ order of $\,a$.

**$\rm\color{#0a0}{Coprime}$ Order Test** $\ o(a)\!=\!p\!=\!{p_1\cdots p_k} \Rightarrow o(a^{p/p_i}) = p_i\,$ & conversely for pair $\rm\color{#0a0}{coprime}$ $\,p_i$

**Proof** $\ (\Rightarrow)\ \ (a^{p/p_i})^n\equiv 1\Rightarrow o(a)=p\mid (p/p_i)n\Rightarrow p_i\mid n,\,$ and $\,(a^{p/p_i})^{p_i}\equiv a^p\equiv 1$.

$\ (\Leftarrow)\,\ a^n\equiv 1\Rightarrow\,(a^{p/p_i})^n\equiv 1\Rightarrow o(a^{p/p_i})\!=\!p_i\mid n,\,$ [thus](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3841440/242) $\,p=p_1\cdots p_k\mid n\,$ by $\,p_i\,$ pair $\rm\color{#0a0}{coprime}$, and $\,a^p \equiv (a^{p/p_i})^{p_i}\equiv 1^{p_i}\equiv 1$

---

**Rad Order Test** $\ \ o(a^k)=n \,\Rightarrow\, o(a)= kn\,$ if all primes $\,p\mid k\Rightarrow \color{#c00}{p\mid n}.\ $

**Proof** $ $ Apply Order Test: $\ 1 \!=\! (a^k)^n\!=\!a^{kn},\ $ but $\,1 \!=\! a^{(kn)/p}\!=\! (a^k)^{\color{#c00}{n/p}}$ contra $\,o(a^k)\!=\!n$

Comment: Interesting answer, but the order test you use talks about every prime divisor of $n$.  However, in your example, you use non-prime divisors 6 and 9.  Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: $18$ has prime divisors $\,p = 2,3\,$ so the test is that $\,a^{18/p}\not\equiv 1\,$ for $\, p = 2, 3.\ $ The test is very useful and should be well-known by every student of number theory and group theory.

Comment: Bill is talking about *maximal* divisors, here-which for any positive integer $n$ are of the form $n/p$ for some prime $p$ that divides $n$. In the case of $18 = 2\cdot 3^2$, the only primes that divide $18$ are $2,3$, so all we need to test is $6 = 18/3$ and $9 = 18/2$. If we were talking about $30$, the maximal divisors would be $6,10,15$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative proof based on knowing that $19\equiv3$ mod $4$ implies $n$ is a quadratic residue mod $19$ if and only if $-n$ is a quadratic non-residue (for $19\not\mid n$), which tells us, to begin with, that $2$ is a non-residue, since $-1\equiv18=2\cdot3^2$ mod $19$ is a non-residue.

There are $\phi(19)/2=9$ quadratic non-residues.  Of these, $\phi(\phi(19))=\phi(18)=6$ are generators of $(\mathbb{Z}/19\mathbb{Z})^*$.  Since $3\mid18$, no cube can be a generator, so $2^3=8$ and $(-4)^3\equiv-2^6=-64\equiv12$ are non-residues that cannot be generators.  Since the non-residue $-1$ is also clearly not a generator, the remaining $6$ non-residues must all be generators, and this includes $2$.

Comment: Yes, from the Order Test (see my answer) we know that $\,a\,$ is a generator $\iff a^9\not\equiv 1\,$ and $\,a^6\not\equiv 1,\,$ i.e. $\,a\,$ is not a square nor a cube.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than employing elementary group theory, we can solve this using three elementary propositions in monoid theory:

Let $\mathcal M$ be a monoid with identity element $e$ and with a finite carrier set.

Proposition 1: An element $a \in \mathcal M$ is invertible if and only if there exists a positive integer $m$ satisfying $a^m = e$. Moreover, if $m$ is the minimal such integer, then the set $\text{<}a\text{>} = \{ a^j \mid 1 \le j \le m\}$ forms a cyclic group with $m$ distinct elements.

Proposition 2: If for $a \in \mathcal M$ where $a \ne e$ there exists a positive integer $m$ satisfying

$$ (a^m)^2 = e$$

then $a$ is invertible and $\text{<}a\text{>}$ contains an even number of elements. Moreover, if $m$ is the minimal such integer, then the set $\text{<}a\text{>} = \{ a^j \mid 1 \le j \le 2m\}$ forms a cyclic group with $2m$ distinct elements.

Proposition 3: If for $a \in \mathcal M$ where $a \ne e$ there exists a positive integer $m$ such that

$$ e \notin \{ a^j \mid 1 \le j \le m\} \, \land \, a^{2m} = e$$

then the set $\text{<}a\text{>} = \{ a^j \mid 1 \le j \le 2m\}$ forms a cyclic group with $2m$ distinct elements.

---

Consider the $\text{mod-}19$ residue classes under multiplication; it forms a monoid. Moreover, it contains $19$ elements and the blocks can be represented as follows:

$$ \Bbb Z/19\Bbb Z = \{ \,[k]_{19} \mid  -9 \le k \le 9  \}$$

Observe that ${[-1]_{19}}^2 = [1]_{19}$ ($[1]_{19}$ is the identity).

Since ${[2^9 ]_{19}} = [-1]_{19}$, all that is needed to show that $\text{<}[2]_{19}\text{>} = \{ {[2^j]_{19}} \mid 1 \le j \le 18\}$ is cyclic with $18$ elements is to check that

$\; [2^4]_{19} \ne [1]_{19}$
$\; [2^5]_{19} \ne [1]_{19}$
$\; [2^7]_{19} \ne [1]_{19}$
$\; [2^8]_{19} \ne [1]_{19}$

(the OP has already calculated $\{2,4,8,7,-1\}$)

But

$\; [2^4 ]_{19} \ne [1]_{19} \text{ iff } [2^6]_{19} \ne [2^2]_{19}$ 
$\; [2^5 ]_{19} \ne [1]_{19} \text{ iff } [2^6 ]_{19} \ne [2^1]_{19}$ 
$\; [2^7 ]_{19} \ne [1]_{19} \text{ iff } [2^9]_{19} \ne [2^2]_{19}$ 
$\; [2^8 ]_{19} \ne [1]_{19} \text{ iff } [2^9 ]_{19} \ne [2^1]_{19}$