# Prove that if $x,y$ are coprime numbers then every odd factor of $x^{2^n}+y^{2^n}$ where $n$ is a positive integer , is of the form $2^{n+1}m+1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove that if $x$ and $y$ have no common factor then every odd factor of $x^{2^n}+y^{2^n}$ where $n$ is a positive integer , is of the form $2^{n+1}m+1$.

---

I have tried using order. Let $k$ be a odd factor of $$x^{2^n}+y^{2^n}.$$ I assumed the order of $x^{2^n}$ w.r.t. $k$ be $m$. So $x^{(2^n)^m} \equiv 1 \pmod{k}$. Now how do I proceed with this idea? I would like to get some hints.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number Theory Problem Using Group Theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2068566/number-theory-problem-using-group-theory) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x%5E%7B2%5En%7D%2By%5E%7B2%5En%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%242%5E%7Bn%2B1%7Dm%2B1%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Afactor%2C%20OR%20content%3Ainteger&p=1). Also, an alternate, with some more detail, explanation is in the AoPS thread [order problem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1731229p11224309). ...

Comment: (cont.) In addition, these two proof methods of the problem are similar to that outlined about [Édouard Lucas' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number#Other_theorems_about_Fermat_numbers) that "Any prime divisor $p$ of $F_n=2^{2^n}+1$ is of the form $k2^{n+2}+1$ whenever $n\gt 1$". Finally, FYI, this other question's [answer](/a/1261595) has a link to [Fermat numbers and Wieferich primes](https://books.google.ca/books?id=SRWneHZWW4kC&pg=PA35&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false), with this having some results & references which might be interesting to you regarding your question.