# For what values of L is $\frac{4\cdot10^{L-1}-7}{3}$ guaranteed to be composite?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, factoring

The sequence $\frac{4\cdot10^{L-1}-7}{3}$ generates numbers of the form 11, 131, 1331, 13331, etc. When $L$ is even then the term is divisible by 11. When $L$ is $15+18k$ then the term is [divisible by 19](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3462899/prove-that-numbers-of-the-form-131-1331-13331-are-divisible-by-19-when-th). It would appear that when the length is 27+28k they are divisible by 29 and when length is 21+30k they are divisible by 31.

Is there some general way to determine arithmetic progressions of $L$ for which terms of the sequence $\frac{4\cdot10^{L-1}-7}{3}$ is guaranteed to have a given factor beyond just guessing and trying to prove each individually?

Comment: When $L$ is $6+16k$, the term is divisible by $17$

Comment: We don't even know all prime [repunit numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3138191/primes-with-digits-only-1)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I guess asking for all values is not a simple question. I guess I am just looking for ways to determine a way to find arithmetic progressions which are composite other than looking at factorization of terms, guessing, and trying to prove individual cases.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner This sequence already has more known [primes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3462941/are-there-an-infinite-number-of-primes-of-the-form-133-331) than repunits... This type of sequence is one way to generalize repunits/repdigits. I am wondering if anyone has looked at sequences of the form $\frac{a\cdot10^n-b}{c}$ in general. It is also an interesting problem to determine when this form is guaranteed to return an integer for all values of n.

Comment: I see you posted [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3464382/for-a-given-a-for-which-values-of-b-and-c-is-the-sequence-fraca-cdot10)

Comment: the difficulty is predicting $10^{L-1}\equiv {7\over 4}\bmod p$ about the only help is that $L$ can never be more than twice $p$, before we have it as a factor if it can factor it at all.