# Find remainder of $2^{20}\div 253$ with specific method

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

[image]

I'm currently doing exercises focused on applying concepts of group theory, Lagrange theorem, orders, homeomorphism. I'm stuck on part **e** of exercise **4**. I guess I'm supposed to use the mentioned concepts to solve this but I can't see how. Besides, since it's the last part of a bigger exercise I think the previous parts have some to do here.

> **e. i)** Find remainder of $2^{20} \div 253$
>
> **e. ii)** Knowing that $2^{55} \equiv -45$  $(mod$ $253)$, find order of $2$ in $U(253)$

Just a clarification, we use $U(n)$ for the *multiplicative group of integers modulo n*

Comment: It helps to note that $253=11\times 23$ so it suffices to solve the problem for $11$ and $23$ independently.  Failing that, [iterated squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) is always a good method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We work in the ring $\Bbb Z/253$. (So equalities are in this ring, we work modulo $253$.)

(i) $2^{20}=(2^{10})^2=1024^2=(1012+12)^2=(0+12)^2=144$.

(ii) $U(253)$ is the group of units $G=U(253)=(\Bbb Z/253)^\times$ in the ring $\Bbb Z/253$. The number of elements of $G$ is $n=\phi(253)=\phi(11\cdot 23)=\phi(11)\cdot \phi(23)=10\cdot 22=220$.

They give us the value for $2^{55}$. Then $2^{110}=(2^{55})^2=(-45)^2=2025=1$. So the order of $2$ divides $110$ by (a), but it does not divide $55$ by (b).

So $2$ is a divisor of $o(2)$. We check first the powers $110/5=22$ and $110/11=10$ of $2$. Well, $2^{10}=1024=12\ne 1$, and $2^{22}=2^{10}\cdot 2^{10}\cdot 2^2=12\cdot 12\cdot 4= 576 = 70$.

So the order of $2$ in $G=U(253)$ is $110$.

Comment: You are implicitly using the Order Test - something which should be made *explicit* (now rectified in my answer). Possibly the OP does not even know that yet.

Comment: In (i), when $(1012+12)^2=(0+12)^2$, what did you do?
I supposed that if $a\equiv b$ $(mod$ $c)$ and $d$ integer then $(a+d)^2 \equiv (b+d)^2$ $(mod$ $c)$ and I just proved it, but is there a more general reason?

Comment: Nevermind, just proved it for $n$ using basic properties.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that they intend to use the [Order Test,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1188614/242) i.e. $\,2\,$ has order $\,110\,$ iff $\,2^{110}\equiv 1,\,$ $\,2^{110/p}\not\equiv 1\,$ for all primes $\,p\mid 110,\,$ i.e. for $\,110/p\,\in\, \{ 110/2\! =\! 55,\ 110/5\! =\! 22,\ 110/11 \!=\! 10\}$.

Another possibility is they intend you to lift its order up from $\bmod 11,23\,$  to $\bmod 11\cdot 23\,$ as below.  Note $\!\bmod Q\!=\!23\!:\ a\equiv 2\equiv 25\equiv 5^2\,$ so the Lemma applies.

**Lemma** $ $ Suppose $\,P=1+2p,\, Q = 1+2q\,$ for primes $\,P,Q,p,q\,$ with $\,(2p,q)=1$.
If $\bmod P\!:\ a^p\equiv -1,\, \color{#90f}{a\not\equiv \pm 1};\  \bmod Q\!:\ a\equiv b^2,\ a\not\equiv 1\,$ then $\,a\,$ has order $2pq\bmod PQ$

**Proof** $\bmod P\!:\ a^{2p}\equiv 1,\ a^{p},\color{#90f}{a^{2}\not\equiv 1}\Rightarrow\ \color{#c00}{o(a) = 2p}\,$ by little Fermat and the Order Test.

$\, $ also: $\ \bmod Q\!:\ a^q\equiv b^{2q}\equiv 1,\ a\not \equiv 1\Rightarrow\, \color{#0a0}{o(a) = q}\ $ similarly, hence

$\ \ PQ\mid a^k-1\!\iff\! P,Q\mid a^k-1\!\iff\! \color{#c00}{2p},\color{#0a0}q\mid k\!\iff\! 2pq\mid k,\, $ so $\,o(a) = 2pq\bmod{PQ}$.

Comment: The Lemma could be generalized further, but hopefully that form already suffices to convey the key idea(s) that they exercise intends to highlight. If you know *quadratic reciprocity* then you may find it helpful to view it from that perspective.