# Why does $k \mid (p-1) /q$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

In **M. Ram Murty**'s paper **Artin's Conjecture on Primitive Roots** I am not able to understand a statement.

> Let $k$ be the order of $a \bmod p$ where $p$ is a prime and also we have $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p$ then $k \mid (p-1)$ if $k \neq p-1$ then $k\mid(p-1)/q$ for some prime divisor $q$ of $p-1$.

I am not able to understand how the author was able to make the second claim *i.e* if $k \neq p-1$ then $k\mid(p-1)/q$ for some prime divisor $q$ of $p-1$.

Comment: See the proof of the [Order Test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1188614/242) in the linked question.

Answer (score 2):

This is a special case of a more general statement: if $k\mid n$ and $k\ne n$ then $k\mid \frac nq$ for some prime divisor $q$ of $n$.

Indeed, this statement holds for any prime $q$ that divides $\frac nk$, which I invite you to verify.

Comment: We have $k \mid n$ and $k \neq n$. let $j$ be an integer such that $kj =n$ now if $q \mid n$ then $q \mid kj$ so, $q\mid j$ or $q \mid k$ now if $q \mid k$ such that $qm = k$ then we have $mj \mid \frac{n}{q}$. How can I conclude from here that $k \mid \frac{n}{q}$ ?