# Find the lowest a such that $17 \mid 3^a-2^a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there any faster method to find the smallest a such that $17 \mid (3^a-2^a) $rather than trying to bash it or how to prove that
$3^{16}-2^{16}$ is the smallest period since we know by euler phi function
$a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p$ for $\gcd(a,p)=1$

Comment: $3^a\equiv 2^a\pmod{17}\implies \frac{3^a}{2^a}\equiv 1\pmod{17}\implies (3/2)^a\equiv 1\pmod{17}$

Comment: Concerning the above comment, I want to clarify that those aren't actual fractions there, but the multiplicative inverse of 2, mod 17, if you aren't aware. Seeing fractions in a congruence certainly threw me for a loop for a second

Comment: yeah so we need to find such a such that $(27)^a \equiv 1 \mod 17$ since $2^{-1} \equiv 9 \mod 17$

Comment: what do we need to do next to reduce $10^a \equiv 1 \mod 17$ do we need to bash a bit? or there is any other method ?

Comment: Provided that we aren't told that $a >0$, wouldn't $a=0$ be the smallest value?

Comment: By Euler's theorem you know that $10^{16}\equiv1\pmod{17}$, and the order of $10$ mod $17$ is a divisor of $16=2^4$. It then suffices to check that $10^8\not\equiv1\pmod{17}$, which is not much work because
$$10^8\equiv((10^2)^2)^2\equiv((-2)^2)^2\equiv4^2\equiv-1\pmod{17}.$$

Comment: $\!\bmod 17\!:\ 3^a\equiv 2^a\iff 1\equiv (3/2)^a\equiv (-7)^a\,$ by $\frac{3}2\equiv \frac{-14}2\equiv -7.\,$ By Fermat $(-7)^{16}\equiv 1$ so by the [Order Test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1188614/242) the least $a$ with $(-7)^a\equiv 1$ satisifes $a\mid 16,\,$ so is a power of $2$, findable by  repeated squareing: $\,(-7)^2\equiv -2$ $\,\Rightarrow (-7)^4\equiv  4$ $\Rightarrow   (-7)^8\equiv -1$ $\Rightarrow  (-7)^{16}\equiv 1\,$ so least $\,a = 16.\ \ $

Comment: Voting to reopen, because this is a special case, where we do not need full order testing. The law of quadratic reciprocity suffices, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way that requires no calculation of modular powers is the following.

1. $17$ is a prime, so there exists an integer $a$ such that $3\equiv2a\pmod{17}$. Think of $a$ as $3/2$ as in the comment of TheBestMagician under the question.
2. $6^2=36\equiv2\pmod{17}$, so $2$ is a quadratic residue modulo $17$.
3. By the law of quadratic reciprocity $3$ is a quadratic non-residue modulo $17$ because $17$ is $\equiv1\pmod4$ and a quadratic non-residue modulo $3$.
4. We can conclude that $a$ is a quadratic non-residue modulo $17$.
5. Therefore (by [Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion)) $a^8\not\equiv1\pmod{17}$.
6. Because $17-1=2^4$ all the proper factors of $16$ are factors of $8$. Therefore item 5 implies that $a$ has multiplicative order sixteen.
7. So sixteen is the smallest period.

---

We similarly see that modulo a Fermat prime every quadratic non-residue is a primitive root. A slight extension of the argument shows that if $p$ and $q=2p+1$ form a pair of Sophie Germain primes, then the quadratic non-residues modulo $q$ other than $-1$ are also primitive roots modulo $q$.

Comment: sorry what is the name $a^8 \ne 1 \mod 17$ theorem since euler had many theorem

Comment: is it primitive root modulo n theorem?

Comment: @GregoriusWillson [This result by Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion).

Comment: None of your answers on the site deserve a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

$10^2\equiv-2,\,10^3\equiv 14\,,10^4\equiv 4,\,10^5\equiv 6,\,10^6\equiv 9,\,10^7\equiv 5,\,10^8\equiv 16\equiv-1$, so $10$ is actually primitive $\pmod {17}$.

Actually you could have checked that using a theorem,  because $10^8\equiv-1\neq1$.

Thus the answer is $16$.

Comment: And of course, to compute $10^8 \pmod{17}$, we can just use $$10^8 \equiv (10^2)^4 \equiv 100^4 \equiv (-2)^4 \equiv 16 \pmod{17}.$$

Answer (score -1):

$2\times 9 \equiv 1 \pmod {17}$ so $9$ is the multiplicative inverse of $2$.

If $17|3^a - 2^a$ then $3^a \equiv 2^a \mod{17}$.

Multiply both sides and we get

$3^a\cdot 9^a \equiv 2^a \cdot 9^a \pmod{17}$

$3^{3a}\equiv 1\pmod {17}$.

We can find out the order of $3$ pretty easily.  It must divide $16$ so it must be $1,2,4,8$ or $16$. We know $3^{16}\equiv 1$ and if $3^k\equiv 1$ then so is $3^{2k}$ so the best strategy is to start with $3^8$ then $3^4$ until we get a value that *isn't* equivalent to $1$.

And $3^8 \equiv 81^2\equiv (-4)^2\equiv 16\equiv -1 \pmod {17}$.

So the order of $3$ is $16$. (We probably knew $3$ was a primitive root by other means but it's slipping my mind how)

So $3^{3a}\equiv 1 \pmod {17}$ means $3a$ must be a multiple of $16$ and as $3$ and $16$ are relatively prime the least common multiple of $3$ and $16$ is $3\times 16$ and $a = 16$.

====

Argh.  Althernatively... As $3^2 \equiv 2^{-1}$ then $2\equiv 3^{-2}\equiv 3^{14}$.

So we need to find the smallest $a$ where $3^a \equiv 2^a \equiv 3^{14a}$ or the smallest $a$ where $3^{13a}\equiv 1$.  So $13a$ is a multiple of the order of $3$ and the smallest $a$ is is the least common multiple of $13$ and the order of $a$.  The order of $3$ is a power of $2$ and so is relatively prime to $13$.  So the least common multiple of $13$ and the order of $3$ is ... $3$ times the order of $3$.

So $a =$ the order of $3$.

Which is $16$.